# How to reference item iterated on inside a v-for?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In the code below I display an image multiple times `n=0,1,2` using a `v-for`, and I wish for an alert with the `n` number corresponding with the image to appear whenever such image is hovered over.

Of course, with the code below I get an `n is not defined` error whenever I hover over an image. What is the correct way to implement the code?

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-for="n in [0,1,2]" v-bind:key="n" 
    src="something.png" onmouseover="alert(n)">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I thought it was `@mousehover="expression"`

Answer (score 0):

**Why it was showing n is not defined**

- `onmouseover` was not pass n to alert param as it was not directive

**we can solve this as follows**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img
      v-for="n in [0, 1, 2]"
      :key="n"
      src="something.png"
      @mouseover="handleMouseOver(n)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleMouseOver(n) {
      alert(n);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```